# Postgres can you disable TOAST to overcome 4B table limit?

Tags: postgresql, storage

I know that PostgreSQL's [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) is automatically used whenever a row size is > 2KB.  However TOAST seems to have a [table limit](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.devel.general/245527) of 4 billion rows.  Is there any workaround, for a larger DB than 4B rows (with large rows) in Postgres?  Is disabling TOAST an option?

Comment: That seems awfully odd. TOAST oid wraparound after 4 billion (i.e. maxint32) writes, with no reuse, vacuum, etc? Wiki page written by one person, with no references, who then posts an answer-to-self on SO for it? **Reference your claims please**. An article written by you does not count. Provide relevant source lines, mailing list posts from credible sources, test results, etc. (Consider that things like temp tables also consume oids).

Comment: Also, if what you say is actually correct for current/recent PostgreSQL versions, please [submit a patch to the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) (or at least post to the docs list) rather than or in addition to posting things like this. Especially without mentioning versions - otherwise we get stale, outdated and confusing info floating around, like people who to this day will tell you "MySQL doesn't support transactions or foreign keys" and point you to some article from 2001 ref'ing MySQL 3.3...

Comment: @CraigRinger  Unfortunately I was able to somewhat validate the gloomy news on the pg-hackers ML, and there doesn't seem to be a workaround.  Corrections welcome obviously.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you can't turn it off [entirely](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAGoODpfw7BeN6POhBPnEhJtmO5LDP5euXqzF1GX-g5nj8WqFmA@mail.gmail.com) (indeed, if you do, you will immediately run into an insertion failure), however, if you modify your storage to `MAIN` type then it will only do "out of line" storage if the row size exceeds 8KB (so possibly less frequently depending on your average row size).  See [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.devel.general/245527) and [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST).